# Use an n-gon for window model?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to make a wall with a window in it:

[image]

I want to get rid of the edges marked in red, but without removing the hole in the middle. I want it like this to make UV unwrapping it more consistant, something like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean more consistent unwrapping? Even if you try to remove the edges they still will be there, because you need at least 8 triangles to create a mesh like that.

Comment: You can't have the hole with no connecting edges to the outside, you **must** have at least one edge connecting the hole to the outer shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better topology would be like this (I believe this is what you are looking for) with the knife tool:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll do that if I can't find a way to do what I wanted to.

Comment: You mean with an n-gon?